# How to update information in the PIN on google map xamarin iOS using API

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I get data from the API and I want to update information in custom pin on google map using iOS project on xamarin.

I declare my CustomPins like that:

```
CustomPin pin1 = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(41.59043006333251, 24.766286971618303),
            Name = "Xamarin", 
            Label = "Bjala river - Smoljan",
            Address = "гр. Смолян",
            CodeNum = 1,
            AlertLevel = 2
        };

customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> {
            pin1,
        };

customMap.Pins.Add(pin1);

customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(41.567797926753485, 25.389703182725665), Distance.FromKilometers(70)));
        Task.Run(async () => await APIConnection(customMap.CustomPins));
```

**My API Connection method look like:**

```
public async Task APIConnection(List<CustomPin> pins)
    {
        
        WaterBindingData waterData = await _restServiceData.GetWaterDataForecast(GenerateRequestUri(Constants.EndPoint), GenerateRequestUriStations(Constants.EndPoint));
        //BindingContext = waterData; 
            
            foreach (var water in waterData.WaterStation.Stations)
            {
            int codeNum = water.CodeNum;
            int level = water.AlertLevelStation;
            int mapcode = water.MapCode;

                foreach (var item in pins)
                {

                if (item.CodeNum == water.CodeNum)
                {
                    item.AlertLevel = level;
                    item.CodeNum = codeNum;
                    item.MapCode = mapcode;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**So in `waterData` come data from this [API](http://194.141.118.43:3001/stations) I want to update `AlertLevel`, `CodeNum` and `MapCode` in the pins with `water.CodeNum;`, `water.AlertLevelStation;` and `water.MapCode;` from the API**.

**PROBLEM:** The problem is there: `waterData` come with data and I debugging this code and he enter in the if else statement and not **Update** the information in the `infoBoxWindow`.. how to fix this problem ?

[image: AlertLevel - "Код на тревога(1-4): 2" and MapCode are not updated .. CodeNum is the same like API data..]

**But the data are here in waterData.WaterStations.Stations**
[image]

**---------UPDATE--------**

I try this way:

```
    foreach (var water in waterData.WaterStation.Stations)
{
    int codeNum = water.CodeNum;
    int level = water.AlertLevelStation;
    int mapcode = water.MapCode;

    foreach (var item in pins)
    {

       if (item.CodeNum == water.CodeNum)
       {
           item.AlertLevel = level;
           item.CodeNum = codeNum;
           item.MapCode = mapcode;
       }
    }
}
customMap.Pins.Clear();
foreach(var item in pins)
{
    customMap.Pins.Add(item);
}
```

And I receive error in main.cs file:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the property while retrieving the list would not update the UI in the map .

Try to clear and readd the items after the loop .

```
foreach (var water in waterData.WaterStation.Stations)
{
    int codeNum = water.CodeNum;
    int level = water.AlertLevelStation;
    int mapcode = water.MapCode;

    foreach (var item in pins)
    {

       if (item.CodeNum == water.CodeNum)
       {
           item.AlertLevel = level;
           item.CodeNum = codeNum;
           item.MapCode = mapcode;
       }
    }
}
customMap.Pins.Clear();
foreach(var item in pins)
{
    customMap.Pins.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: On the last line customMap.Pins = pins; 
I receive error: Property or indexer Map.Pins cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: I receive another error in the main.cs Object reference not set to an instance of an object check my update

Comment: Can you figure out which line cause the error ? Try to use `Try catch`.